Actives ph adjustments doubts
I hope someone can answer my question please.
Should I measure the pH value after each addition of active ingredients in my cosmetic formula to ensure that the active ingredient remains within its stability range?"
For example, I have an Alpha Arbutin serum that is stable at a pH of 5-7. I added aloe vera juice to the water, and when I measured the pH, I found it to be 3.8.Should I raise the pH to 5 for the Alpha Arbutin, or is it unnecessary?
Thanks in advance.

Well, you should adjust final pH.

If one ingredient is pH sensitive the better procedure would probably be to adjust the pH of any additive solutions to acceptable levels before mixing.

Is glycolic acid ph sensitive?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
